# C# binary serialization error

Tags: c#, json, json.net, serializable, binaryformatter

So here it goes,

I have the following JSON string:

```
{"sTest":"Hello","oTest":{"vTest":{},iTest:0.0}}
```

And I have de-serialize it using Newtonsoft.JSON as the following:

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json)
```

The problem is, I have a requirement that requires me to serialize that object into a binary file using BinaryFormatter. And by doing the following:

```
Stream stream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/_etc/") + "obj.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
serializer.Serialize(stream, e.props);
stream.Close();
```

I got an error saying:

> Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not marked as serializable.

I have no idea how to continue. Is there something i'm missing? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `BinaryFormatter`, you'll need to create serializable classes to match the data in your JSON. So for example:

```
// I'm hoping the real names are rather more useful - or you could use
// Json.NET attributes to perform mapping.
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public string sTest { get; set; }
    public Bar oTest { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Bar
{
    public List<string> vTest { get; set; }
    public double iTest { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize from JSON to a `Foo`, and then serialize that instance.

Comment: does that mean that i can't serialize dynamic object into binary file? is there another work around that allows me to do so? Anyways, many thanks, mate!

Comment: @GalihDonoPrabowo: Well there's no such thing as a "dynamic object" really - you're trying to serialize a `JObject`. The `BinaryFormatter` has no idea that your variable uses `dynamic`. Personally I'd recommend trying to get rid of the requirement - the .NET binary formatter is pretty fragile and annoying in various ways... if your real requirement is a compact representation, there are lots of other options. (And "binary file" doesn't imply "using .NET binary serializatoin" necessarily...)

Comment: Likely marking the class with [`[Serializable]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be simpler than implementing [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Requirement dropped! Thanks a bunch guys! [^_^]